# SSH setup properly but ansible cannot connect

Tags: ssh, ansible

My SSH using keys is setup properly.

```
sudo ssh 10.112.57.193
Last login: Fri Jul 22 06:46:09 2016 from 10.112.56.104
root@10.112.57.193 [ ~ ]#
```

`ansible-playbook` run with -vvvv gives below:

```
fatal: [10.112.57.193]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": false, "msg": "OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h-fips  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket \"/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-10.112.57.193-22-root\" does not exist
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.112.57.193 [10.112.57.193] port 22.
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: timeout: 9999 ms remain after connect
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6 pat OpenSSH_6.5*,OpenSSH_6.6* compat 0x14000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to 10.112.57.193:22 as 'root'
debug2: compat_kex_proposal: original KEX proposal: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: Compat: skipping algorithm \"curve25519-sha256@libssh.org\"
debug2: compat_kex_proposal: compat KEX proposal: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/root/.ssh/known_hosts\"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.112.57.193
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1,hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: zlib@openssh.com,zlib,none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes256-ctr,aes128-ctr
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 zlib@openssh.com
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:EzWODeV66ep6Tdb/AKGeSdNQDItF2ynnSgwl3AWFJZ4
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file \"/root/.ssh/known_hosts\"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 10.112.57.193
debug1: Host '10.112.57.193' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7ff51fe43280),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug3: input_userauth_banner
\nVMware vCenter Server Appliance 6.5.0.5100\n\nType: vCenter Server with an embedded Platform Services Controller\n\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: ,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg ssh-rsa blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:+LtQFZZg4ODIS9pt8BkU/NeO/84Yo3Fz9aXPmO/Q2Kc
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:+LtQFZZg4ODIS9pt8BkU/NeO/84Yo3Fz9aXPmO/Q2Kc
debug1: Enabling compression at level 6.
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 10.112.57.193 ([10.112.57.193]:22).
debug1: setting up multiplex master socket
debug3: muxserver_listen: temporary control path /root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-10.112.57.193-22-root.Tkrk06Le6APUt3iA
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 5 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 0: new [/root/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-10.112.57.193-22-root]
debug3: muxserver_listen: mux listener channel 0 fd 5
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x08
debug1: control_persist_detach: backgrounding master process
debug2: control_persist_detach: background process is 1571
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: forking to background
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: schedule exit in 60 seconds
debug1: multiplexing control connection
debug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: fd 6 is O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [mux-control]
debug3: channel_post_mux_listener: new mux channel 1 fd 6
debug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1: hello sent
debug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: cancel scheduled exit
debug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x00000001 len 4
debug2: process_mux_master_hello: channel 1 slave version 4
debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
debug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x10000004 len 4
debug2: process_mux_alive_check: channel 1: alive check
debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 1573
debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
debug3: mux_master_read_cb: channel 1 packet type 0x10000002 len 283
debug2: process_mux_new_session: channel 1: request tty 0, X 0, agent 0, subsys 0, term \"xterm\", cmd \"/bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469171730.18-277524960696371 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1469171730.18-277524960696371=\"` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469171730.18-277524960696371 `\" ) && sleep 0'\", env 0
debug3: process_mux_new_session: got fds stdin 7, stdout 8, stderr 9
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug2: fd 9 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug2: process_mux_new_session: channel_new: 2 linked to control channel 1
debug2: channel 2: send open
debug2: callback start
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 2
debug1: Sending command: /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p \"` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469171730.18-277524960696371 `\" && echo ansible-tmp-1469171730.18-277524960696371=\"` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469171730.18-277524960696371 `\" ) && sleep 0'
debug2: channel 2: request exec confirm 1
debug3: mux_session_confirm: sending success reply
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 2: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
debug2: channel 2: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 2
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 2
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug3: mux_exit_message: channel 2: exit message, exitval 1
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 2 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 2: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 2: close_read
debug2: channel 2: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 2: rcvd ext data 123
mkdir: cannot create directory ?/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469171730.18-277524960696371?: No space left on device\ndebug2: channel 2: written 123 to efd 9
debug2: channel 2: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 2: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 2: obuf empty
debug2: channel 2: close_write
debug2: channel 2: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 2: rcvd close
debug3: channel 2: will not send data after close
debug2: channel 2: send close
debug2: channel 2: is dead
debug2: channel 2: gc: notify user
debug3: mux_master_session_cleanup_cb: entering for channel 2
debug2: channel 1: rcvd close
debug2: channel 1: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 1: close_read
debug2: channel 1: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 2: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 2: is dead
debug2: channel 2: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 2: free: client-session, nchannels 3
debug3: channel 2: status: The following connections are open:
  #2 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 fd -1/-1 cc -1)

debug2: channel 1: obuf empty
debug2: channel 1: close_write
debug2: channel 1: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 1: is dead (local)
debug2: channel 1: gc: notify user
debug3: mux_master_control_cleanup_cb: entering for channel 1
debug2: channel 1: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 1: is dead (local)
debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 1: free: mux-control, nchannels 2
debug3: channel 1: status: The following connections are open:

debug2: set_control_persist_exit_time: schedule exit in 60 seconds
debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
debug2: Received exit status from master 1
", "unreachable": true}

        to retry, use: --limit @/usr/share/xml/scap-compliance/scripts/10.112.57.193.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
10.112.57.193              : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

I have other machines for which this works without any issues. Not sure what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error messages says:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ?/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469171730.18-277524960696371?: No space left on device
```

By the way, do you connect to a box that can run python code?
If not, you should use only `raw` module.

Comment: No, that `mkdir` error is because of no connection. There is plenty of space on the target box. Yes, the target box can run python very well. There are other similar systems that work without any issues. Python version is 2.7.11 on the target box.

Comment: I think there IS a connection. How's `$HOME` parsed into `/root` then? May be some troubles with encoding? Why path in error message is surrounded by `?` and not by `"`? Try some simple call with `raw` module (touch a file or something) to rule out the connectivity problem. @praving5

Comment: Thanks a ton. Indeed. The connection did exist. The target dir was getting full very soon and hence my "time of check" and "time of use" let me believe that there is plenty of space in the drive on the target. I cleared up space and it just worked without any qualms. Thanks a lot. You spotted the right thing.